# How to use glDrawBuffers with JOGL?

Tags: opengl, jogl

The OpenGL code written with C++ is like this:

```
static const GLenum buffs[] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
glDrawBuffers(1, buffs);
```

And I found the same API in JOGL:

```
gl.glDrawBuffers(int n, IntBuffer bufs)
```

I don't know how to port that C++ code above to JOGL with this method. Anyone knows? Thanks.

Comment: why not creating an IntBuffer containing only GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0? The rest stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it nearly the same way as in C++

```
IntBuffer buffer = BufferUtil.newIntBuffer(1);
buffer.put(GL.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);

gl.glDrawBuffers(1, buffer);
```

Comment: Rather call newDirectIntBuffer so that JOGL doesn't have to create a direct buffer for you. It's more "future proof" as we're not sure that we will go on allowing the use of indirect NIO buffers in the next major versions of JOGL.

Comment: By the way, use the class "Buffers" as BufferUtil doesn't exist in JOGL 2.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/GL2ES2.html), there are two overloaded entry points for `glDrawBuffers()` in JOGL. There's the one you already saw with the `IntBuffer` argument, but also [this one](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/GL2ES2.html#glDrawBuffers(int,%20int[],%20int)):

```
void glDrawBuffers(int n,
                   int[] bufs,
                   int bufs_offset)
```

It takes an array of draw buffer values, as well as an offset into the array. If the values are at the start of the array, the offset would be 0. So your call becomes:

```
int buffs[] = {GL.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
gl.glDrawBuffers(1, buffs, 0);
```

Comment: I have a problem using the framebuffer, would you mind taking a look at this post? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179885/wrong-framebuffer-status-return-36054-when-try-to-do-depth-attachment)

Comment: Please use the right documentation, fix your comment: http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/GL2ES2.html#glDrawBuffers(int,%20java.nio.IntBuffer) @Reto Koradi You use a link to a completely obsolete Oracle documentation for an extremely old (2010) version of JOGL 2.

Comment: @gouessej Take in account you can edit comments also by youself ;)

Comment: @elect I know I can edit them by myself but Reto Koradi often answers to OpenGL questions and I'd like him to know where to find the latest documentation so that it will pick the right one next time.

Comment: @gouessej I edited in the latest documentation links a couple of days ago, after you commented on it.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
gl.glDrawBuffers(1,new int[]{GL.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0},0);
```

Comment: Better to avoid int arrays, because in this way you can manage directly off-heap memory and be sure it gets deleted