# Wrong framebuffer status (return 36054) when try to do depth attachment

Tags: opengl, jogl

Here is the code setting up a framebuffer for shadow mapping, yet it returns 36054 when checking the framebuffer status. Any ideas?

```
//bind framebuffer for shadow mapping
gl.glGenFramebuffers(1, framebuff);
gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL4.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuff.get(0));

gl.glGenTextures(1, textureBuff);

gl.glBindTexture(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureBuff.get(0));
gl.glTexStorage2D(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL4.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, displayWidth, displayHeight);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL4.GL_LINEAR);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL4.GL_LINEAR);//GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR
gl.glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL4.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL4.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

gl.glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL4.GL_COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL4.GL_LEQUAL);
gl.glFramebufferTexture(GL4.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL4.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, textureBuff.get(0), 0);
gl.glDrawBuffer(GL4.GL_NONE);

if(gl.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL4.GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL4.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    return gl.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL4.GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
```

Comment: Are `displayWidth` and `displayHeight` non-zero?

Comment: It means that the attachment is incomplete, maybe it's hardware related. It can happen if your hardware isn't capable enough. Please give us much more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed. The displayWidth and displayHeight were set during the reshape function, and assigned 0 by default before it was assigned in the reshape function, thus it was 0 at the time setting up buffers, which broke the rule.